# in VS, How to tell the compiler to break when a Specific Variable is Storing a Specific Value?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging

Is there a way In VisualStudio to tell the compiler to break 
when i reaches the value 5 for example ?

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a breakpoint on the `for` statement (or anywhere in the loop body where `i` is in scope,) then right click the red dot in the margin and choose "condition..." and enter the expression `i == 5`

It's as easy as that.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, using the [Debugger](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debugger.aspx) class:

```
if (i == 5) System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```